# IndexError returned on curve_fit: error on function call?

Tags: python, curve-fitting, index-error

I am trying to use `curve_fit` given this function

```
def F(xy,*p):
    x,y = xy
    c = np.array(p).ravel()

    n = (len(c)-1)/4
    omega = pi/180.0

    z = c[0]
    for t in range(n):
        z += c[4*t+1] * (cos((t+1)*omega*x))
        z += c[4*t+2] * (cos((t+1)*omega*y))
        z += c[4*t+3] * (sin((t+1)*omega*x))
        z += c[4*t+4] * (sin((t+1)*omega*y))

    return z


def G(xy,*p):
    x,y = xy
    c = np.array(p).ravel()

    ngm = (len(c))/7

    z = 0
    for t in range(ngm):
       a  = c[7*t]
       cx = c[7*t+1]
       mx = c[7*t+2]
       sx = c[7*t+3]
       cy = c[7*t+4]
       my = c[7*t+5]
       sy = c[7*t+6]

       z += a * np.exp(-((cx*(x-mx)**2)/(2*(sx**2)))-((cy*(y-my)**2)/(2*(sy**2))))

 return z

def FG(xy,*p):
    x,y = xy
    c = np.array(p).ravel()

    nf = int(c[0])
    ng = int(c[1])
    print nf,ng

    pf = [c[i] for i in range(2,4*nf+3)]
    pg = [c[i] for i in range(4*nf+3,4*nf+7*ng+3)]

    z1 = F(xy,pf)
    z2 = G(xy,pg)

    return z1+z2

pfit,cov = opt.curve_fit(FG,xy,z,p,bounds=bounds)
```

I am sure that the shape of both `p` and `bounds` are appropriate. I tried printing `nf` and `ng`, and they are properly printed until after some number of iterations (around after 20th function call, not the same in every run), where the values changed significantly.

After the 20th (or more) run, it returns the following error:

```
File "/Users/pensieve/calcs/3D_AA/0_codes/fitpkgs.py", line 144, in FGfit
pfit,cov = opt.curve_fit(FG,xy,z,p,bounds=bounds)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scipy-0.18.1-py2.7-macosx-10.10-intel.egg/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 683, in curve_fit
**kwargs)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scipy-0.18.1-py2.7-macosx-10.10-intel.egg/scipy/optimize/_lsq/least_squares.py", line 878, in least_squares
tr_options.copy(), verbose)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scipy-0.18.1-py2.7-macosx-10.10-intel.egg/scipy/optimize/_lsq/trf.py", line 128, in trf
loss_function, tr_solver, tr_options, verbose)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scipy-0.18.1-py2.7-macosx-10.10-intel.egg/scipy/optimize/_lsq/trf.py", line 341, in trf_bounds
f_new = fun(x_new)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scipy-0.18.1-py2.7-macosx-10.10-intel.egg/scipy/optimize/_lsq/least_squares.py", line 764, in fun_wrapped
return np.atleast_1d(fun(x, *args, **kwargs))

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scipy-0.18.1-py2.7-macosx-10.10-intel.egg/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 455, in func_wrapped
return func(xdata, *params) - ydata

File "/Users/pensieve/calcs/3D_AA/0_codes/fitfunctions.py", line 65, in FG
pgm = [c[i] for i in range(4*nf+3,4*nf+7*ng+3)]
IndexError: index out of bounds
```

For reference, I use scipy 0.18.1.

Comment: Your bounds exceed the length of `c`. Check to make sure they don't? Also if you just want a subset of `c` use array slicing instead.

Comment: Yes, I see that. The `curve_fit` still passed the array correctly (I print `nf` and `ng` inside the function to check), and it returned correct dimensions properly until after some iterations, which yield the error above. From the functions above, `c` is not changing (or am I missing something?)

Comment: I am not familiar with the specific `curve_fit()` function, but I suspect that if you print out `len(c)` in addition to `nf` and `ng`, you will see that either it is changing, or they are changing. As for why exactly, I do not know enough about how `curve_fit()` uses them.

Comment: Also side note, you should be using slicing anyway, but since this is Python 2.7 use `xrange()` instead of `range()`, so you don't create the whole list that you don't really use anyway.

Comment: sorry, `curve_fit` just pertains to `scipy.optimize.curve_fit`. For the last comment, thanks for the suggestion. I am a newbie with Python!